# How can I automatically add pictures in Tableau Tooltip?

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I created a Tableau Workbook/Dashboard to easily view (by state) a list of all the growers in our network. Within Tableau, I can easily view the company's info with the Tooltip and a linked window to their website. But, my employers would like me to add images directly into the tool tip, so that when the cursor hovers over a specific shipper, both their information and images of their products are displayed. Below is a link to my public test workbook.

https://public.tableau.com/profile/glen2530#!/vizhome/Test1_15935250992760/Dashboard1?publish=yes

Comment: Is there any reason this is tagged "Excel"?

Comment: @BigBen I have Tableau connected to an excel file as my data source. So I didn't know of that tag needed to be included because this solution might need me to edit the data source first. I've encountered a few similar problems/solutions and they all involved editing the data source 1st.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to use the [Viz in Tooltip](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/viz_in_tooltip.htm), where you display another worksheet in the tooltip. This will be some work in your case; you would need to get all of the images and [use them in Tableau as custom shapes](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/2/how-use-custom-shapes-filters-your-dashboard-50200).

You could create a worksheet with all of the growers and their images as shapes. Then, using the above viz in tooltip, filter that worksheet in the tooltip to only return that growers image.

Comment: Thanks. Another problem is that I have a list of over 900 growers. Is there any way to automatically tie the pictures to the specific growers website?

Comment: That is a problem. It would create a long time to not only source all images, they would then need individually attaching to a grower in your data.  There must be a better way to do this...but I don't know it. Perhaps worth asking as a new question.